# SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing with .format and for loop

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to do this loop but I get this error, any advice?

```
for file in glob.glob("results/dir_bam/*_dedup.bam"):
  f_name = file_name(file)
  cmd = 'java -jar {} GenomeAnalysisTK ' \
        '-T IndelRealigner ' \
        '-R {} '\
        '-I {} ' \
        '-targetIntervals {} ' \
        '-known 1000G_phase1. InDels .hg19. VCF ' \
        '-known Mills_and_1000G_gold_standard. InDels .hg19. VCF '\
        '-o aligned_reads.sorted.dedup.realigned. BAM' \
        .format(picard, path_ref_gen, file,
                'results/dir_bam/' + f_name + '.intervals', 
                'results/dir_bam/' + f_name + '_realigned.bam')
```

> SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

I tried with different tabs and spaces but I didn't work. The problem comes from the .format part.

Comment: Strange, this code runs OK on my machine (after I add an `import glob`). Are you sure the code in this question exactly matches the code you're running?

Comment: No line number? No exact line?